# Как через запрос multipart/form-data отправлять массивы и bool?

Tags: golang, post, rest, типы-данных, multipart

Пишу `API` на `GoLang` и хочу реализовать получение данных об "продукте" в перечень которых входит помимо строковых и числовых переменных массив строк и bool.

В голове уже возникла идея передать *массив как строку с запятыми*, а *bool как 1 и 0 для true и false соответственно*.

Хотел бы спросить есть ли другой способ для расшифровки напрямую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для парсинга boolean-ов можно использовать `strconv.ParseBool(r.FormValue("NameOfField"))`